# Limit RAM usage of docker on linux

Tags: linux, docker, ram

In windows we can specify the RAM limit for WSL thus limiting the RAM usage of **docker as a whole**.

Can i do something similar in **linux**?

Google search only shows way to limit the usage of induvudual containers.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Consider that WSL  *is* a "container" itself. It is even possible to start two WSL instances at the same time on Windows. So it is equivalent.

Comment: @MadFred i need to limit the ram usage in linux.

Comment: If you run all your docker containers as a specific user, you can use cgroups to limit memory usage of that user.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt that seems to be a good idea.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, and I don't know if docker understand cgroups and limits resources, or whether it just gets killed when it exceeds memory limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit memory and CPU on docker daemon with help of systemd unit:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537645/how-to-limit-docker-total-resources

Answer (score 0):

As explained by the [Docker Official Guide](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/) you can set limits on memory and cpu (this one only for **swarms**).

Comment: These are per-container limits and the OP needs an overall limit